# How to filter array of daterange?

Tags: javascript

I'm building calendar booking feature where business manager have certain working time and some of this time is booked. Use should be able to choose slot to prevent overbooking

App should get a new array with all available time ( selectableTimes minus bookedTime ), minding the timeframe period ( start - end )

If someone has a similar experience, I found appreciate any ideas to what direction should I be looking. Thanks

```
// time when you can possibly book a meeting
// aka working time
const selectableTimes = [
  "8:00", "8:30", "9:00", "9:30",
  "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30",
  "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30",
  "14:00", "14:30", "15:00", "15:30",
  "16:00", "16:30", "17:00", "17:30",
  "18:00", "18:30", "19:00", "19:30",
  "20:00"
]

// my calendar is booked on (api responce)
const bookedTime = [
  {start: "16:30", end: "17:30"},
  {start: "18:15", end: "19:00"}
]

// build new array with available dates
let availableDates = selectableTimes.filter( x => {
      // check every event in api responce
      bookedTime.map( ev => {
        // I'm stuck :)
        ev.start < x ? true : false
      })
    })

// should get something like
const result = [
  "8:00", "8:30", "9:00", "9:30",
  "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30",
  "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30",
  "14:00", "14:30", "15:00", "15:30",
  "16:00",
  "19:00", "19:30",
  "20:00"
]
```

Comment: Why selectable times at all? It's enough to have a start and an end, then just check the booked time ranges instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// I generate the hour:minute from 08:00 to 20:30
const selectableTimes = [];

for (let i = 8; i < 20; i += 1) {
  selectableTimes.push(`${i}:00`);
  selectableTimes.push(`${i}:30`);
}

// my calendar is booked on (api responce)
const bookedTime = [{
    start: '16:30',
    end: '17:30',
  },
  {
    start: '18:15',
    end: '19:00',
  },
];

// transform the hour:minute to comparable number
function t(v) {
  const [
    hour,
    min,
  ] = v.split(':');

  return Number(hour) * 60 + Number(min);
}

// filter the values
// The Array.some is used to see if the selectable time is
// inside of a booked period
const filtered = selectableTimes.filter(x =>
  !bookedTime.some(y => t(y.start) <= t(x) && t(y.end) >= t(x)));

console.log(filtered);
```